# ¿Cómo obtener el valor ingresado en un campo de Texto HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, web, aplicación-web

Necesito insertar un Monto en un campo de texto ...al salir de ese campo, debo calcular el impuesto sobre ese monto (impuesto = monto * 0.12) también el total ( total = monto + impuesto)  y establecer estos valores en otros campos de texto automáticamente.

Código HTML

```
<input type="text" id="Monto" name="Monto" placeholder="Monto" onchange="CalculoIva()" required />
<input type="text" id="Iva" name="Iva" placeholder="Iva"  required />
<input type="text" id="Total" name="Total" placeholder="Total"  required />
```

Estoy intentando esto pero no funciona

```
 <script lang="javascript" type="text/javascript">
       var monto = 0;
       onchange = CalculoIva();
       function CalculoIva() {
           monto = document.getElementById('Monto').innerText ;
           var iva = parseFloat(monto) * 0.12;
           var total = parseFloat(monto) + parseFloat(iva);
           document.getElementById("Iva").innerHTML = iva.toString();
           document.getElementById("Total").innerHTML = total.toString();
       }
   </script>
```

Comment: No funciona, pero por qué. No se ejecuta el evento? no es el valor deseado? Que tipo de error te da?

Comment: No me da error simplemente no obtiene el texto la variable monto es vacio

Comment: En vez de `.innerText` en la `var monto` usa `.value`. Además al inicializar la `var` a `0` se hace tipo `int`. y el valor de un campo de texto es `string`. has de parsear y comprobar que el valor en efecto es `int` antes de asignarlo

Comment: y el código onchange = CalculoIva(); q tienes dentro del código javascript en la 3 linea creo que tampoco te hace falta

Comment: el `onchange` de HTML hace referencia directamente a una función javascript que hayas definido. No necesitas almacenarla en una variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He refactorizado un poco el código de la respuesta de [sioesi](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/30373/6491)

- Eliminado *inline* javascript en HTML
- Los inputs: `iva` y `total` cambiado a `readonly`
- La función `CalculoIva()` es ahora *reutilizable*
- Verifica si el valor de `monto` es numérico
- Resetea todos los campos si no es un numero válido
- Cambiado el punto por comma (Standard Europeo)
- Formato resultado `iva` y `total` a 2 decimales (0,00)

```js
function CalculoIva(monto, iva, total) {
  
  montoParse = parseFloat(monto.value);
  
  if (typeof montoParse === 'number' && !isNaN(montoParse)) {
    
      var ivaCalc   = montoParse * 0.12;
      var totalCalc = montoParse + ivaCalc;
    
      iva.value   = ivaCalc.toFixed(2).replace('.', ',');
      total.value = totalCalc.toFixed(2).replace('.', ',');
    
  } else {
    
      iva.value   = '';
      total.value = '';
      monto.value = '';
      console.log('Introduce un numero válido');
  }
}

var monto = document.getElementById('Monto');
var iva   = document.getElementById('Iva');
var total = document.getElementById('Total');


monto.onchange = function(){ CalculoIva(monto, iva, total); }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="Monto" name="Monto" placeholder="Monto" required>
<input type="text" id="Iva" name="Iva" placeholder="Iva"  readonly>
<input type="text" id="Total" name="Total" placeholder="Total" readonly>
```

Answer (score 3):

Debes hacer algo asi

```js
function CalculoIva() {
    var monto = document.getElementById('Monto').value;
    if(isNaN(monto)){
        alert("Introduce un numero, por favor");
        document.getElementById('Monto').value = "";
    }else{
        var iva = parseFloat(monto) * 0.12;
        var total = parseFloat(monto) + parseFloat(iva);
        document.getElementById("Iva").value = iva;
        document.getElementById("Total").value = total;
    }
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="Monto" name="Monto" placeholder="Monto" onChange="CalculoIva();" required />
<input type="text" id="Iva" name="Iva" placeholder="Iva" required />
<input type="text" id="Total" name="Total" placeholder="Total" required />
```